# How to fix rasterio error: The EPSG code is unknown. Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio

I try to open a jp2 image with the Python's Rasterio package. The code is below. The problem is that the coordinate reference system is not recognised and when I want to see the meta attribute of the opened band I see that the crs is None.

```py
import rasterio
b6_path = 'D:\\IKI\\1np\\myimage_band06.jp2'
b6 = rasterio.open(b6_path, driver='JP2OpenJPEG')
b6.meta

#output:
# {'driver': 'JP2OpenJPEG',
# 'dtype': 'uint16',
# 'nodata': None,
# 'width': 5490,
# 'height': 5490,
# 'count': 1,
# 'crs': None,
# 'transform': Affine(20.0, 0.0, 699960.0,
#        0.0, -20.0, 4900020.0)}
```

As I know what the coordinate system is, I tried to set it manually like this:

```py
import rasterio.crs
crs = rasterio.crs.CRS({"init": "epsg:32634"})
b6.crs = crs
```

But when I call the CRS() function I get this error message:

```py
CRSError: The EPSG code is unknown. Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv.  Try setting the GDAL_DATA environment variable to point to the directory containing EPSG csv files.
```

I checked the GDAL_DATA variable by this command in the Anaconda prompt:

echo %GDAL_DATA%

the path to which the variable points to is: C:\Users\me\Miniconda3\Library\share\gdal

This folder contain a file named gcs.csv where the coordinate systems info should be so I do not know what is the problem? I found this discussion:

https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/issues/1539

but it is too complicated for a beginner like me. Also, there seems to be no solution clearly stated there.

I am using Windows 10, Python 3.7, Miniconda 3, rasterio 1.0.28, and gdal 2.4.2

Comment: Does the gcs.csv have the 32634 COORD_REF_SYS_CODE defined?

Comment: @nmtoken No, there is no projection with this code defined in the file. This is strange because this is the code of WGS84/UTM zone 34N which is a common projection. Where to find the correct .csv file/s?

Comment: In fact, gcs.csv contain the geographic coordinate systems. The pcs.csv file has the projected coordinate systems including UTM. I don't know why the error message mentions gcs.csv.

Comment: Have you activated your conda environment before you run the script? It's activation of the environment that is required to set GDAL_DATA correctly (see https://github.com/conda-forge/libgdal-feedstock/blob/22683f0bb727e6fcdf83e450e00566e632b30b28/recipe/scripts/activate.sh#L6).

Comment: Not related, but important: your rasterio usage above is incorrect. Always use `CRS.from_epsg(32634)` instead.

Comment: I have the same qestion